# Rosbag and timestamp received vs timestamp published

Tags: ros, rosbag, time

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can't find it anymore but I seem to recall reading somewhere that when you record a rosbag, the timestamp encoded to the message is the time at which the message was received by the rosbag record process instead of the time at which it was published.

If this is true, is there a way to force a rosbag to instead encode messages with the timestamp which were published with them?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230230/rosbag-and-timestamp-received-vs-timestamp-published/) by [JustinBlack02](https://answers.ros.org/users/26403/justinblack02/) on ROS Answers with karma: 131 on 2016-03-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-03-29**:
If I may suggest: please re-open the question, post your *edit* as an answer and accept your own answer. That makes it a bit clearer that the question was actually answered - instead of just closed.

**Comment by [JustinBlack02](https://answers.ros.org/users/26403/justinblack02/) on 2016-03-30**:
I tried, but it looks like I don't have enough points to reopen my question.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-03-31**:
I've re-opened it for you.

**Comment by [JustinBlack02](https://answers.ros.org/users/26403/justinblack02/) on 2016-03-31**:
Done, still need 10 points to accept my own answer though :/

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-03-31**:
I've just given you 10 points. You should be able to accept it now.

**Comment by [JustinBlack02](https://answers.ros.org/users/26403/justinblack02/) on 2016-03-31**:
Answer accepted and question closed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems the premise of this question is partly incorrect.

Although rosbag does store the time at which a message is a received, the time stamps aren't stripped and replaced with a new one but rather the entire stamped image is recorded (along with the publishing time stamp) as a `sensor_msgs/Image` which still contains the original `Header`.

---

Originally posted by [JustinBlack02](https://answers.ros.org/users/26403/justinblack02/) with karma: 131 on 2016-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TouchDeeper](https://answers.ros.org/users/39695/touchdeeper/) on 2020-12-27**:
Hi, I still don't understand your answer. Did you mean that the timestamp of the message is the timestamp when the entire message is recorded? Is the timestamp recorded in the bag different from the original message timestamp?